# How to calculate age via datatable

Tags: sql, .net

I'm making a project to save details of elephants, and then when they are dead, I need to calculate their age and display it in a textbox. To retrieve the saved birthday of a given elephant, I'm using a data table. And then, I intend to find the age by subtracting the birth year from the current year.

Here is the code:

```
String elid = cmbidentyno.SelectedItem.ToString();
con.Open();

String select_query = "SELECT ElephantName,DOBirth FROM ElephantData WHERE ElephantID='" + elid + "'";
cmd = new SqlCommand(select_query, con);

SqlDataReader R = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (R.Read())
{
    txtelname.Text = R.GetValue(0).ToString();
    DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime birth = DateTime.R.GetValue(2);
    int age = now.Year - birth.Year;
    txtdesage.Text = age.ToString();
}

elid = cmbidentyno.SelectedItem.ToString();
con.Close();
```

But this does not work. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: I'm getting building errors even before executing the code.

Comment: What are the errors? Is DOBirth an actual datetime field? I think you might be referencing a non-existent column are part of that line as well.

Comment: Yes,DOBirth is a datetime field(actually,I've defined it as only a date field.But it does not matter,right?)

Comment: The error says " 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'R' ".

Comment: I think you want `DateTime birth = (DateTime)R.getValue...`. GetValue() will always return a string, you need to cast it to DateTime to put that into a DateTime variable.

Comment: Yeah,i tried it.Then it says " 'System.DateTime' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' "

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Unrelated tip: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that you don't need to call Close: it will be called as it exits the using block. And rather than `R.GetValue(0).ToString();` prefer `R.GetString(0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ...
> DateTime birth = DateTime.R.GetValue(2);
> ...
> ```

In `DateTime` there is no property `R`.

If you want to read a `DateTime` use [`GetDateTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.7.2). So the line in questions in your code becomes:

```
...
DateTime birth = R.GetDateTime(2);
...
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine.Thank You!